# How to Count number of Non-Number Words in Excel using VBA Function

Tags: excel, vba, string, function

For Example, 
I'd like a String such as, "This is a Bunch of Words in a sequence of 13 possible 1 words from a Dictionary or BookZZ or Libgen.io 1876" to give me a result of 19 (because "13", "1876" and "1" are numbers and should not be counted).

I created Two Functions which I'm trying to use within this Function I'm asking about:

The first one is the following:

```
' NthWord prints out the Nth Word of a String of Text in an Excel Cell such 
' as A1 or B19.

Function NthWord(ActiveCell As String, N As Integer)

Dim X As String
X = ActiveCell

X = Trim(Mid(Replace(ActiveCell, " ", Application.WorksheetFunction.Rept(" 
", Len(ActiveCell))), (N - 1) * Len(ActiveCell) + 1, Len(ActiveCell)))

NthWord = X

' In the Excel SpreadSheet:
' Trim (Mid(Substitute(A1, " ", Rept(" ", Len(A1))), (N - 1) * Len(A1) 
' + 1, Len(A1)))

End Function
```

The second one is the following:

```
'NumberOfWords returns the number of words in a String 

Function NumberOfWords(ActiveCell As String)

Dim X As String
X = ActiveCell
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

If Len(Trim(X)) = 0 Then
    i = 0
Else:
    i = Len(Trim(X)) - Len(Replace(X, " ", "")) + 1
End If

NumberOfWords = i


' In the Excel SpreadSheet
' IF(LEN(TRIM(A1))=0,0,LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)


End Function
```

My Attempt at printing the NumberOfNonNumberWords

```
Function NumberOfNonNumberWords(ActiveCell As String)

Dim X As String
X = ActiveCell
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
Dim i As Integer

If NumberOfWords(X) > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To NumberOfWords(X)

        If Not (IsNumeric(NthWord(X, i).Value)) Then
            count = count + 1
        End If

    Next i
End If


NumberOfNonNumberWords = count

End Function
```

However, when I apply this function in the Excel Worksheet, I get an output of 
`#VALUE!`
and I'm not sure why. How do I fix this?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISNUMBER(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))))`

Comment: How about a word that is a mixture of numbers and letters.......... *I like A1 steak sauce.*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent mmmmmm *Steak*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent If we'd like to Count the number of Words that include a mixture of numbers and letters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the whole string then count non-numeric elements.

```
function abcWords(str as string) as long

    dim i as long, arr as variant

    arr = split(str, chr(32))

    for i=lbound(arr) to ubound(arr)
        abcWords = abcWords - int(not isnumeric(arr(i)))
    next i

end function
```

[image]

Comment: How does the `abcWords = abcWords - int()` work? `int()` will return a `1`, or `0` correct? When you don't first declare `abcWords` as something, how does it work to subtract from itself?

Comment: In VBA, *True* is numerically minus one, not one like it is on the worksheet.

Comment: Would this not add up the number of numeric words then?

Comment: @BruceWayne, like any undeclared var, an undeclared function is a variant by default instantiated numerically as zero, so if you start adding or subtracting numbers to/from a variant, you will end up with numbers.

Comment: @Brotato, my bad; the logic was reversed. fixed above.

Comment: @Jeeped 
Though A1 is a string, If I use abcWords(A1) in the Excel Worksheet, it will not work I don't believe? Shouldn't we use `abcWords(ActiveCell)` instead?

Comment: @AdamStaples, Don't understand why you would be having issues. See img added above.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `SPLIT()` to split the text on a space delimiter, then count the non-numeric words:

```
Function num_words(ByVal text As String)
Dim txt_split
txt_split = Split(text, " ")

Dim total_words As Long
total_words = 0

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(txt_split) To UBound(txt_split)
    If Not IsNumeric(txt_split(i)) Then
        total_words = total_words + 1
    End If
Next i
num_words = total_words
End Function
```

Comment: Our solutions were basically the same so I removed mine and +1 although I would ditch the temporary place holder `total_words`

Comment: I Changed the input to `ActiveCell As String` and then declared
`Dim text As String`
and got the result I was looking for. Thanks very much!

Comment: @AdamStaples - "Passing ByRef or ByVal indicates whether the actual value of an argument is passed to the CalledProcedure by the CallingProcedure, or whether a reference...is passed to to the CalledProcedure. If an argument is passed ByRef, the memory address of the argument is passed to the CalledProcedure and any modification to that parameter by the CalledProcedure is made to the value in the CallingProcedure. If an argument is passed ByVal, the actual value, not a reference to the variable, is passed to the CalledProcedure." - [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx)

Comment: @urdearboy - Ah! I didn't realize I didn't need the placeholder. I thought once I set the UDF name (`num_words`) to a value, it exits the routine.  I'll leave it for OP here, but thanks for telling me that! Going forward I won't use them anymore :D

Comment: The true value won’t be assigned until the loop completes! See @Jeeped solution for working example :)

Comment: @urdearboy - Yeah, his answer is quite clever.  So was my thinking correct, if that was *not* in a loop, and I did say `num_words = 1 // num_words = 2`, it would exit the function and return `1`?

Comment: The function will always result in your last definition of `num_words`, so in your example, the output would be 2.